# Extjs and Spring MVC XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

Tags: java, spring, extjs, cors

When I call from sencha:

```
proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8585/academy/api/alumno/list/',
                        reader: {
                             type: 'json',
                             rootProperty: 'alumnos'
                        }
                    },
```

I receipt on spring mvc:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/alumno")
public class AlumnoController {

    @Autowired
    AlumnoApi alumnoApi;

    @RequestMapping(value = "list", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<DtoAlumno> findAll(){
        return alumnoApi.findAll();
    }
```

Showing the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8585/academy/api/alumno/list/?_dc=1467319530160. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

if I open the address: http://localhost:8585/academy/api/alumno/list/?_dc=1467319530160 in the browser shown json file correctly

I have activated the plugin Toggle CORS, if I turn off Toggle shows an error CORS.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue on a server where the services are on the same server but the DB is not.

**Setup:**

1. Ubuntu 14 server (not on localhost)
2. Tomcat running on port 8080 (application runs standard port 80 outside tomcat)
3. Domain assigned to IP of server (root reaches application, :8080 reaches tomcat services)
4. .htaccess file to limit access to services.

**Problem**
Calling Extjs.dataStore.read() would throw a 400 series error with preflight error having invalid HTTP. (same as OP above)

**Solution**
Update .htaccess file to include proxy rewrite and don't use port in URL for datastore.

The base URL within the browser must match your pre-service call, port and all, for the URL given to the Extjs.dataStore.proxy.url

**Example:**

URL in browser:

```
http://localhost:5517/MyApp  //(this is your EXTJS app location note the port number)
```

In Extjs:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.myDataStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.myDataStoreModel',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'myDataStore',
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'MyApp.model.myDataStoreModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'http://localhost:5517/mainservice/subservice?q=test', //URL localhost:<port> needs to match URL in browser (or use domain without ports)
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: function(data) {
                        console.info('data ='); console.info(data); return data; //show raw return 
                    }
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
//Ext.StoreMgr.get('myDataStore').read(); //to call read event
```

in .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLnks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^mainservice/subservice(.*)$ http://localhost:8585/mainservice/subservice$1 [P]
```

**Worth noting,**
I cannot test this in localhost as my spring services are attached to other servers / databases outside what I can reach with a localhost.

The moment the browser's URL doesn't match the URL referenced in the proxy spring will give the error you have above.

I don't know if this will help you as you don't appear to be using an .htaccess file but it could help others who are experience similar issues as it was how I found your post.